# Having trouble fixing memory leaks

Tags: c, memory-leaks, free

```
void insert_queue (queue_ref queue, queue_item_t item) {   
   queuenode_ref new = malloc(sizeof (struct queuenode));
   assert(new != NULL);
   new->item = item;
   new->link = NULL;

   if (!isempty_queue(queue)) {
      queue->rear->link = new;
      queue->rear = new;   
   } else {
      queue->front = new;
      queue->rear = new;
   }
}
```

I'm having hard time fixing memory leaks in this function. I tried to **free(new)** at the end of the function, but it still doesn't fix the leaks. Where should I put this statement?

Comment: To fix memory leaks due to `malloc`, simply keep track of all `malloc`s and free all the memory `malloc`'ed after use. That means if `free(new)` doesn't solve your problem then problem is elsewhere. Please post rest of the code with explanation.

Comment: @MadHatter: so the **new** is done using after the if-else statement, is that not where I should put free(new)?

Comment: What makes you say this is leaking memory? Usually the leak happens when you don't properly free memory - here is you creating an item in the queue and that's OK. How do you _remove_ things from the queue - I suspect that's where the problem lies.

Comment: @GavinZ. : No, I don't think so, since you did `queue->rear->link = new; queue->rear = new;` so that means you have put the memory allocated to `new` in use. Now you can only  `free` it if you want to remove this node from the queue.

Comment: Actually, you should free this `new` only after you never need it, and the end of `insert_queue()` definitely not the right place to free it. You are going to use `queue->front` or `queue-rear` later, right?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are creating a linked list, and the insert_queue() function adds an element to that list. This means that after you call this function 10 times, there should be a queue somewhere in memory with 10 elements in it. The idea is that you can then use this queue somewhere else in your program.

If you clean up all of the allocated memory inside insert_queue(), then you will not be able to grow your queue. The memory leak is wherever you get rid of your queue after you are done with it. If you do nothing, then those 10 elements will hang around in memory until your entire program exits.

You should do two things. In your remove_queue() function (the one that removes elements from the queue), you should call free() on the removed node. And also, if the queue is not empty by the time you are done with it, then you should call remove_queue() on all remaining elements to make sure you return the memory they are occupying back to the system.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a memory leak in this function. The job of the function is to allocate a new queue node so that the item can be added to the end of the queue - thus, it should only be freed when pulling from the queue (presumably in another function you have written).

Calling `free()` in this function would create memory corruption, where the item you added would point to invalid memory.

You should call `free()` in your `pull_from_queue()` (or similar) function, once you have retrieved the queue_item ready for returning.

Answer (score 0):

There are no memory leeks in this function. You shall free() memory in the function where you remove element from the queue.

Another approach is to pass already constructed element to `insert_queue()` and also free memory for the element returned from `remove_queue()` such memory management (allocation/free) happens on the same level above your `insert_queue()` & `remove_queue()` functions.